# curve_fit making called func raise an IndexError

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to fit a parameter eta_H in function TGp_xx to some data (x_data, data_num_xx) using curve_fit. Now, the code below is a reduced version of what I'm using and it won't work by itself, but I hope the issue is conceptual enough to be understandable even from this

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

Lx        = 150
y_cut     = 20

data = np.loadtxt("../dump/results.dat")

ux       = data[:,3]
ux       = np.reshape(ux       , (Ly, Lx))


def Par_x(x,y,vec):
    fdx = vec[(x+1)%Lx    , y]    
    fsx = vec[(x-1+Lx)%Lx , y]    

    return (fdx - fsx) / 2.0

def TGp_xx(x, eta_H): return 2*eta_H*Par_x(x,y_cut,ux)

x_data = np.arange(Lx, dtype=np.int)
data_num_xx  = np.empty(Lx, dtype='float64')  #this is just a placeholder

popt_xx, pcov_xx = curve_fit(TGp_xx, x_data, data_num_xx)
```

I get an IndexError raised within Par_x:

```
fdx = vec[(x+1)%Lx    , y]
```

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

I tried something simpler like calling TGp_xx(x_data, some_constant) outside curve_fit, and it works. I don't really get why inside curve_fit i get the IndexError, as if I'm passing a float value (or an array of floats) as x, that can't be used as an index.

Comment: At the start of `Par_x` (and/or `TGp_xx`) add a print that shows the arguments, `x,y,vec` - may be with type and dtype information.  Remember, those are called via `curve_fit`.

Comment: The issue seems to be that, indeed, inside Par_x called via curve_fit x is an array of floats; before curve_fit the dtype is int64. I honestly have no idea how to force curve_fit to keep the correct dtype

Comment: Please, provide sample data too

Comment: No need to waste your time. A data type conversion inside Par_x will do the job. Thanks

Comment: Look at `curve_fit` code.  It does explicitly convert `xdata` and `ydata` to float.  Under normal curve fitting that makes sense.

Comment: got it, thanks. Should have checked beforehand